# Deadlock using Java Logging Framework

Tags: java, logging, deadlock

Here is the behavior:

I run the application which logs stuff to the file and console pretty often. This morning it got hung up. Method run by a thread did not return for over an hour. Once I pressed enter on command line, it continued on. Using JConsole, I was able to extract the only suspicious thing that I saw (JConsole did not detect any deadlocks).

Here is the log for the method that ran for over an hour:

```
Name: Thread-4
State: RUNNABLE
Total blocked: 38  Total waited: 56,153

Stack trace: 

java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
   - locked java.io.BufferedOutputStream@9b96a26
java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:480)
   - locked java.io.PrintStream@6be7e9c6
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
   - locked java.io.OutputStreamWriter@46a4fd82
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
java.util.logging.StreamHandler.flush(StreamHandler.java:242)
   - locked java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler@79ff8609
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:106)
java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:522)
java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:543)
java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:607)
com.mycomp.myproj.util.Log.log(Log.java:126)
com.mycomp.myproj.util.Log.logWarning(Log.java:79)
com.mycomp.myproj.eng.engine.runEngine(RunEngine.java:397)
com.mycomp.myproj.eng.engine.runEngine(RunEngine.java:297)
com.mycomp.myproj.eng.engine.runEngine(RunEngine.java:288)
com.mycomp.myproj.ModelYear.runYear(ModelYear.java:118)
com.mycomp.myproj.Monitor.runModel(Monitor.java:749)
com.mycomp.myproj.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:37)
```

Can someone give me tips on what could be wrong, how to solve, was resources to view?

Comment: At a guess I'd say it was waiting for the file, did some other thread/process hold a lock on the file?

Comment: I ran seperate instances, however, I made sure only the first instance had a FileHandler (only first instance wrote to the log file). Nothing else writes to the log file. This is the log from the first instance (second instance did not get hung up). Additionally, even if they do both write at the same time, the second instance we create a secondary file log.log2 and write there.

Answer (score 0):

> Once I pressed enter on command line, it continued on.

Seems that the console is requesting that the output be blocked.

For instance, the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) documentation lists the following warning:

> Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, or even deadlock.

Even the console is a process.

Comment: Is that possible without explicitly scanning Std In? Can command line buffer get too large and unable to clear?

Comment: I’m skeptical too but, from what you have posted those are the first two questions that I would prove to troubleshoot this.  Also, how is your program launched?  What O/S and JVM are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit. Latest 64bit JDK. I started the process using ProcessBuilder with Std Err redirected to Std In. I read only one stream right after I start the process. I am aware of that warning, and I think there is nothing I can do more to read any faster.

Comment: What is launching the java.exe?  The data flow is from ConsoleHandler -> System.err -> j.i.FD.err -> java.exe -> ????

Comment: Ant does set up, runs javac and jars the code. Ant runs a bat file that open a command prompt that runs the jar.